# How do I change my delimiter from comma to a semicolon?

Tags: c#, csv

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Reflection;
using CsvHelper.Configuration;

namespace ReadCsvFile
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public DataTable ReadCsv(string filename)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Data");
            using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"" +
                Path.GetDirectoryName(filename) + "\";Extended Properties='text;HDR=yes;FMT=Delimited(;)';"))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(string.Format("select *from [{0}]", new FileInfo(filename).Name), cn))
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        adapter.Fill(dt);
                    }
                }
            }

            return dt;
        }

        private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "CSV| *.csv", ValidateNames = true, Multiselect = true })
                {
                    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                        dataGridView.DataSource = ReadCsv(ofd.FileName);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It turned out that the csv files I tried to read had semicolons (`;`) as separators, instead of the usual commas (`,`).

I tried to change the delimiter, but for some reason was not able to.

I would appreciate any help I could get!

Answer (score 1):

I would *guess* that you just need to change this:

```
using (OleDbConnection cn = new 
          OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"" +
               Path.GetDirectoryName(filename) + 
               "\";Extended Properties='text;HDR=yes;FMT=Delimited(;)';"))
```

to this:

```
using (OleDbConnection cn = new 
          OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"" +
               Path.GetDirectoryName(filename) + 
               "\";Extended Properties='text;HDR=yes;FMT=Delimited(,)',"))
```

Change the `FMT=Delimited(;)';` in the OleDb connection string to be `FMT=Delimited(,)',`

**UPDATE:** Sorry, I misunderstood your original question - you've *already* changed the delimiter to `;` in your `OleDbConnection` - missed that one.

Quite honestly: I have no idea how and what you should do (in addition to what you've already done) to get this `OleDbConnection` and command to work properly...

Personally, I would use the excellent (and free!) [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) component to read any CSV files I might need to import - not that OleDb stuff..... with `CsvHelper`, it's very easy to define delimiters (and many more properties of your import), and it works like a charm, returning a `List<YourEntity>` from any `.csv` file, ready to be used whichever way you want

Comment: I already changed it from (,) to (;).

Comment: Because I need the delimiter to be (;). Because the.csv files apparently now use a (;) as a separator instead of (,)

Comment: @Red-X: ok - so you've changed it already - and it doesn't work? Do you get any kind of error? If so: please post here.

Comment: @marc-s I don't get an error. It reads the file but it displays it all in one column, because it didn't read the semicolon(;) as a separator.

Comment: @Red-X: I personally would use [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) to read CSV files - not that OleDb stuff..... with CsvHelper, it's very easy to define delimiters (and many more properties of your import) ....