# Import txt file into MS Access with query

Tags: c#, ms-access

I need to import file txt into Access db with a query (c# in asp.net).
But the format of a txt can be change and use `, ;` for the delimiter.
I have different file.txt with different delimiter and for this i don't want to change the OleDb connection string.

I have found this :

```cs
queryString = @"SELECT * INTO new FROM [Text;IMEX=2;FMT=Delimited(;);HDR=no;CharacterSet=437;Database=<PATH>].File.txt";
command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, con);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This code work, but all data is in the same column.
I don't know to define `;` as delimiter for a special file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change my delimiter from comma to a semicolon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089722/how-do-i-change-my-delimiter-from-comma-to-a-semicolon)

Comment: @NatPongjardenlarp That's not applicable. If you want to store the result in an ACCDB file, you can't use the Jet OLEDB provider, and the ACE provider ignores FMT= altogether, it queries format information from the registry (terrible design choice, I know).

Comment: @ErikA Did you know a solution for load data from txt into different or the same ACCDB file with different delimiters

Comment: Yes, but I don't have a C# IDE set up at the moment, so I can't write up a proper answer. Sorry. You can either create Schema.ini files for each file you're importing (as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14634287/7296893) or [in the docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver?view=sql-server-2017) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/initializing-the-text-data-source-driver), or manipulate the registry and create a new connection afterwards.

Comment: @ErikA Thank for help. 
Something else may be used instead of ACE? I do not have any special constraints ( just c #)

Comment: You could use Access automation with `DoCmd.TransferText` to import text files, but I recommend you just go with creating schema.ini files (you can delete them after you've imported the file). If you're working with accdb files, your options are ACE, Access automation (which uses ACE internally), and third-party stuff you really shouldn't touch.